# Automatically link sources file to an XCode project

Tags: xcode, applescript

Im auto-generating C/C++ source code from another IDE and would like to add/remove the source(s) files automatically to an open XCode project to be compiled.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to "link" to XCode a folder where it can find all the source files to compile?

Or I absolutely need to write and manually run an AppleScript each time?

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found that basically parsing and editing the .xcodeproj package content is the easiest route.